# The Laurent Series of $\sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)}$ at the point $z=\infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How can we find the Laurent Series of $\sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)}$ near point $z=\infty$? By definition, it's equivalent to asking the Laurent Seires of $\sqrt{\frac{(t-1)(t-2)}{t^2}}$ near the point $t=0$. The singularities are $t=0,1, 2$ but the square-root function is multivalued. So we have to define a branch cut $[-\infty,0]$, $[1,2]$. But all points on the branch cut is obviously non-analytic. So can we say the Laurent Series do not exist?

Comment: You don't *have* to choose the specific branch cuts you made; it is not mandatory to make the choice you did. And I don't think $\infty$ is really the primary problem for you. Let's take a simpler situation. Based on the concerns you have, what would you say is the Laurent series for $\sqrt{z}$ at $z = 1$?

Comment: @KCd, could you expand on what you mean?  It seems to me that since $\sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)}$ has a branch point at $\infty$ it can't have a Laurent series there; it's not analytic in any punctured neighborhood of $\infty$.

Comment: Strin is asking about "the" Laurent series, but that is not a well-defined concept even for $\sqrt{z}$ at $z=1$. Next I would ask what Strin would say about a Laurent series for $\sqrt{z}$ at $z = 0$, just to avoid involving $\infty$ as part of the issue.

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken.  The function does not have a branch point at $\infty$ after all.  It turns out that off-by-one errors are kind of important when talking about winding numbers!

Comment: @KCd I see, you mean it's not possible to define the Laurent Series at points like $z=0$ for $\sqrt{z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a branch of $\sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)}$ that has its branch cut on the interval $[1,2]$, and is thus analytic in a neighbourhood of $\infty$.  If $z = 1/t$, we write
$(z-1)(z-2) = (1-t)(1-2t)/t^2$ and take $\sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)} = \sqrt{(1-t)(1-2t)}/t$.  Note that $\sqrt{(1-t)(1-2t)}$ (using the principal branch of the square root) is analytic 
in a neighbourhood of $t=0$.

Comment: But we have to define the branch cut [-$\infty$, 0] in addition to [1,2], for otherwise the function is multi-valued at 0 and discussion of analytic is not allowed. If we defined that branch cut, we cannot say the function is analytic at $\infty$.

Comment: Sorry........$\infty$ is not a branch point and you're right. By the way, it's not possible to define Laurent Series at $z=0$ for $\sqrt{\frac{(t-1)(t-2)}{t}}$ right?

Comment: Right, $\sqrt{(t-1)(t-2)/t}$ has a branch point at $0$ because $\sqrt{1/t}$ does.