# Understanding the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+11}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, branch-points

I want to understand the function: $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+11}} dz$.

This functions seems to have two branch points $\sqrt{11}i$ and $-\sqrt{11}i$. Does it also have a brunch at $\infty$? Usually $\infty$ is a branch point of $Log(z)$ and I don't think it cancels here, but I am not sure.

Another thing, it seems $\sqrt{11}i$ and $-\sqrt{11}i$ are also poles of $f(z)$. So are those points both poles and branch points? How should I consider them?

Also something that I would like to understand is: since we define $\sqrt{z^2+11} = exp(\frac{1}{2} Log(z^2+11))$ and the exponent never reaches $0$, are those points really a singularity?

After all this, where is the function analytic? Is $f(z)$ analytic in $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-\sqrt{11}i,\sqrt{11}i]$? What about the branch point of $\infty$?

Can I prove that the function is analytic in $\{|z| > \sqrt{11} \}$?

Finally, is how do I expand $f(z)$ to a power series (Taylor or Laurent)?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to carefully read the answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147262/the-laurent-series-of-sqrtz-1z-2-at-the-point-z-infty?rq=1. It's true that the branch points there are at $z = 1, 2$ rather than $z = \pm \sqrt{11} i$...but if you let $w = z/i$, then as a function of $w$ you have branches at $\pm \sqrt{11}$; let $t = \frac{w + 3 \sqrt{11}}{2\sqrt{11}}$ and you end up with branches at $t = 1, 2$, so the problems are (up to a linear change of variables) identical.

Comment: Is that supposed to be an integral? The differentials don't match.

Comment: Well I do want to integrate this function afterwards, but I first want to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a branch so that $\infty$ is a removable singularity, the branch cut running, say, on the imaginary axis from $-\sqrt{11} i$ to $+\sqrt{11} i$.  Namely, write
your function as 
$$ \frac{1}{z \sqrt{1 + 11/z^2}}$$
with the principal branch of the square root.  Note that $1 + 11/z^2 \in (-\infty, 0]$ if and only if $z$ is on that branch cut.

Comment: Thanks, I do note that. Could you show how exactly $\infty$ is a removable singularity? Another thing, when I calculate the integral of the function on $|z|=5$, I change variables to $w=\frac{1}{z}$ and then I can either use the residue theorem on the pole at $0$ or  expand it into Laurent series and use Cauchy's formula. Right?

Comment: Please also mention using ‘generalized binomial theorem’ to expand it into a Laurent series.

Comment: @GabiG It's removable because the function is analytic in a deleted neighbourhood of $\infty$ (i.e. in $\{z: \;|z| > \sqrt{11}\}$) and has a finite limit ($0$) at $\infty$.

Comment: If you're integrating this branch around $|z|=5$, you'll run into the branch cut.

Comment: This is why I used change of variables